# Retrieving more than 100 tweets from twitter API using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, twitter, async-await

I'm trying to retrieve more than 100 tweets from Twitter in nodejs. however, I keep getting an empty array. I tried this way:

```
const MAX_TWEETS = 200;
const TWEETS_PER_REQUEST = 100;

async function retrieveTweets(T,parameters,tweets_data,request_num){
    T.get('search/tweets', parameters, function (error, data){
        let lowest_id = null;
        let tweets = data.statuses;
        for(var i=0;i<tweets.length; i++){
            tweets_data[request_num*TWEETS_PER_REQUEST+i] = tweets[i].text;
            if(!lowest_id || lowest_id>tweets[i].id){
                lowest_id = tweets[i].id;
            }
        }
        parameters.max_id = lowest_id;
    }); 
}

async function twitter(){
    var config = require('./config.js');
    var Twit = require('twit');
    var T = new Twit(config);

    var parameters = { q: 'obama', count: TWEETS_PER_REQUEST, result_type: 'recent' };
    var tweets_data= new Array(MAX_TWEETS);
    await retrieveTweets(T,parameters,tweets_data,0);
    await retrieveTweets(T,parameters,tweets_data,1);
    console.log(tweets_data);
}

twitter();
```

and I have no idea why I keep getting an empty array. Any help would be much appreciated.

edit: I do get results from the get request but when I try to save them in the `tweets_data` array, I get an empty array and the results don't end up saving.

Comment: Start by visiting the URL in your browser, do you get any tweets? Then add some error handling, and see what Twitter actually returns

Comment: @adeneo I do get results from the Twitter API. when I add console.log(tweets) inside the get request I get the results but in the twitter() function it displays an empty array.

Comment: you're passing `tweet_sizes` to `retrieveTweets` not `tweets_data` is this what you want?

Comment: @JDunken noo..this was a typo. I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling the promises correctly.
The get request can return a promise, so instead of using async change the function to

```
function retrieveTweets(T,parameters){
    return T.get('search/tweets', parameters); 
}
```

then in the twitter function

```
await retrieveTweets(T,parameters).then(data => {
 // do stuff with result
}.catch(error => {
 // do stuff with the error
}.finally(() => {
 // finish up
}
```